# Vim with ACK: Search for all #pragma not ending in once

Tags: c++, regex, ack

Using ACK in Vim, I want to find all instances of `#pragma` that does not end in `once` within C++ related files. What is the regex I need to use?

`#pragma\s+.*(?<!once)$` works in Python and JavaScript, but I'm not sure how to get ACK to accept it.

`:Ack --cpp #pragma\s+.*(?<!once)$` produces the following error in Vim:

> E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#'

Escaping the `#` with `\\\` returns nothing. I have tried a few other modifications, but I'm not getting what I want.

Comment: Have you tried the same expression but with `grep`?

Comment: Yes grep returned nothing as well. I guess I could expand the question to "or grep".

Comment: How's your `:Ack` command defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `#` and the `!` with a single backslash.

e.g.

```
:!ack-grep --cpp '\#pragma\s+.*(?<\!once)$'
```

I am unsure if `:Ack` runs the same in the background.